# \obeylines doesn't work in Expl3 conditionals

Tags: macros, conditionals, expl3

I'm having trouble with `\obeylines` when it occurs inside an `expl3` conditional, but no problems in a normal TeX conditional.

What's going on? And can I alter the `expl3` conditional in some way to make it work?

### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_new:N \l__dcp_tmp_int
\int_set_eq:NN \l__dcp_tmp_int \c_one_int
\prg_new_protected_conditional:Npnn \__dcp_if_tmp_one: { T }
  {
    \if_int_compare:w \l__dcp_tmp_int = \c_one_int
      \prg_return_true:
    \else:
      \prg_return_false:
    \fi:
  }
\cs_set_eq:NN \ifdcptmpone \__dcp_if_tmp_one:T
\ExplSyntaxOff
\newcount\dcptmpint
\dcptmpint=1
\begin{document}
\begingroup
\ifdcptmpone{%
  \obeylines
  Yes,
  tmp
  $=$
  one
}
\endgroup

\medskip

\begingroup
\ifnum\dcptmpint=1\relax
  \obeylines
  Yes,
  tmp
  $=$
  one
\fi
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image: output]

Comment: You can't, catcode are frozen once the argument is tokenized. Nevertheless you can choose to use v-type argument to grab the argument then use `\scantokens` to rescan it.

Comment: @user202729 not only catcodes, all eol are spaces in the argument so I don't think this is recoverable at all. Davd, you need to define `\ifdcptmpone` with no argument that sets up obeylines then calls an internal helper to grab

Comment: @DavidCarlisle If the argument is read and tokenized under verbatim-catcode-régime according to `+v`-type, eol yield character-tokens of category 12 whose character code comes from the value of `\endlinechar`. Would setting `\newlinechar=\endlinechar` right before doing `\scantokens` do the trick?

Comment: @UlrichDiez not really, `\obeylines`  puts an active character `\let` to `\par` on each line. `\newlinechar` wouldn't do that.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Let's say `\scantokens` is like writing a file from a set of tokens and then inputting that file under current catcode-régime.  The `\newlinechar=\endlinechar`-thingie is in effect only while `\scantokens` writes the fake-file from the `+v`-argument.  `\obeylines` is inside `\ifdcptmpone`'s `+v`-argument and thus is carried out and is effective when - after `\scantokens` has written the fake-file from the `+v`-argument - inputting that fake-file takes place. At least this is what I did in my answer. Seems to work out.

Comment: @UlrichDiez hmm OK I suppose you are right:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Me? Thank you. ;-)  But with this question it was originally suggested by user202729.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle In my answer I assumed that `%` is treated as a comment-character when `\scantokens`' inputting of the fake-file takes place and thus can be used for "neutralizing" the last `\endlinechar` inserted by `\scantokens`. Do you know a trick for neutralizing `\scantokens`' last endline-character in case you cannot rely on usual catcode-régime being current when `\scantokens` is carried out?

Comment: @UlrichDiez use luatex and `\scantextokens` ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, that's what I do when using a LuaTeX-engine. I wonder whether there is a good trick in case LuaTeX is not available. I suppose not - otherwise I would already have seen it in some code-snippet of yours some years ago. ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am unable to understand what you are solving in the Expl3 part of your macros (because it is unreadable to me) but if you insist on the syntax `\ifdcptmpone{\obeylines ...}` then you can do this as follows:

```
\newcount\dcptmpint
\dcptmpint=1

\def\ifdcptmpone{\ifnum\dcptmpint=1 \else \expandafter\ignoreit \fi}
\def\ignoreit#1{}

\ifdcptmpone{%
  \obeylines
  Yes,
  tmp
  $=$
  one
}
```

Comment: I heard you love `Exp3` ;). Although this works with the trivial example in my MWE, it doesn't work with arbitrary content with the `\obeylines` appearing somewhere unknown within some other macro.

Comment: @DavidPurton I think the token `\obeylines` being brought up via reading/tokenizing  from .tex-input-file or via expansion-cascade initiated by some macro shouldn't matter as in case of `\dcptmpint`'s value being 1  `\ifdcptmpon`'s argument actually is not used as a macro argument but just forms a local scope. Inside that local scope `\obeylines` will be effective from the moment when TeX encounters it.  Can you provide a code-snippet exhibiting the problem?

Comment: @UlrichDiez, actually, now I can't! Although a moment ago I thought I could :(/

Answer (score 3):

Not really related to expl3. While scanning the argument all ends of lines make space tokens so by the time the body executes `\obeylines` there are no lines to obey.

You need to set up `\obeylines` before scanning the argument:

```
\documentclass{article}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_new:N \l__dcp_tmp_int
\int_set_eq:NN \l__dcp_tmp_int \c_one_int
\prg_new_protected_conditional:Npnn \__dcp_if_tmp_one: { T }
  {
    \if_int_compare:w \l__dcp_tmp_int = \c_one_int
      \prg_return_true:
    \else:
      \prg_return_false:
    \fi:
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__dcp_if_tmp_two:Nn#1#2{
\__dcp_if_tmp_one:T#1{#2}
\endgroup}

\cs_new:Npn \ifdcptmpone{
\begingroup
\obeylines
\__dcp_if_tmp_two:Nn
}

\ExplSyntaxOff
\newcount\dcptmpint
\dcptmpint=1
\begin{document}
\ifdcptmpone{%
  Yes,
  tmp
  $=$
  one
}

\medskip

\begingroup
\ifnum\dcptmpint=1\relax
  \obeylines
  Yes,
  tmp
  $=$
  one
\fi
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ta. This seems basically unavoidable. I don't specifically need the `\obeylines`. I just have a test that could have anything in, and happened to notice that when that anything included an environment with `\obeylines` it didn't work. I guess that's why `\obeylines` isn't really used regularly. Makes for nice syntax for my purposes though. Can't be helped.

Comment: @DavidPurton `\obeylines`  is like `\verb` it's only usable as a top level declaration that changes syntax rules. It is not usable without pain in the argument of any command

Answer (score 1):

*Giving a command other than a TeX `\newif`-conditional a name which starts with `\if..` is bad practice because when nesting such commands inside `\if.. ... \else ... \fi`-expressions occurs, you are easily confused about proper `\if..`-`\else`- `\fi`-nesting.*

*That's why in the following example the command is not named `\ifdcptmpone` but is named `\doifdcptmpone`.*

---

As indicated in the [comment of user202729](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/665451/obeylines-doesnt-work-in-expl3-conditionals#comment1654736_665451) you can have `\ifdcptmpone` read its argument as a vebatim-argument (`+v`-type) and use `\scantokens` for re-scanning it—just set `\newlinechar=\endlinechar` before calling `\scantokens` to make sure endline-characters cause `\scantokens`' fake-file-writing-part to continue writing in a new line:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_new:N \l__dcp_tmp_int
\int_set_eq:NN \l__dcp_tmp_int \c_one_int
\prg_new_protected_conditional:Npnn \__dcp_if_tmp_one: { T }
  {
    \if_int_compare:w \l__dcp_tmp_int = \c_one_int
      \prg_return_true:
    \else:
      \prg_return_false:
    \fi:
  }

% let's also do s.th. about horizontal-tab which wouldn't be treated correctly by +v-type otherwise:
%
\NewDocumentCommand \doifdcptmpone {} {\group_begin: \char_set_catcode_other:N \^^I  \doifdcptmponeinner}

\group_begin:
\char_set_catcode_other:N \%
\use:n {
  \group_end:
  \NewDocumentCommand \doifdcptmponeinner {+v} {\group_end: \__dcp_if_tmp_one:T {\begingroup\newlinechar=\endlinechar\scantokens{\endgroup~#1%} } }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\newcount\dcptmpint
\dcptmpint=1
\begin{document}
\begingroup
\doifdcptmpone{%
  \obeylines
  Yes,
  tmp
  $=$
  one
}
\endgroup

\medskip

\begingroup
\ifnum\dcptmpint=1\relax
  \obeylines
  Yes,
  tmp
  $=$
  one
\fi
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Impressive. This works with my real code which has the `\obeylines` buried in a macro, halfway through too.

Comment: @DavidPurton If you don't mind the braces that surround the argument of `\ifdcptmpone`  forming a local scope, then [wipet's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/665735/118714) is the better approach.

Comment: wipet's answer only works if the argument starts with `\obeylines`. If have something else in the argument it fails.

Comment: What kinds of side effects are there with your answer?

Comment: @DavidPurton If with wipet's approach `\obeylines` is moved, e.g., behind the line `tmp`, then with the line `$=$` and the line `one` llines will be obeyed. This is the behavior I would expect. I don't understand what scenario you have in mind where wipet's approach might fail while mine does not.

Comment: @DavidPurton Side effects/drawbacks: 1) It is relied on `\doifdcptmpone` obtaining the tokens that form its argument by reading and tokenizing stuff from the .tex-input-file. If the tokens forming the argument are passed by another macro things fail. 2) It is relied on `\doifdcptmpone`'s argument not permanently changing the catcode of `%`. 3) It is relied on `\endlinechar` having value 13. 4) It is relied on `\doifdcptmpone` being called while the standard-catcode-régime is in effect. 5) It is not expandable but does temporary assignments to `\newlinechar` and category-code of horiz. tab.